# How can I categories Nouns taken from a text file using Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, text, nltk, text-mining

From a business article I want to extract the words that defines the nature of business it is talking about. For example, if the article contains the words like 'Retail Banking' or 'Courier Service' or 'Steel Plant', we can get a get about the business.

`

```
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *
from nltk import *
import csv
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
Text=open('bbb_2.txt')
t=Text.read().lower().decode('utf8')

tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(t)


posTagged=pos_tag(tokens)

nnp=[(wrd,tags) for (wrd,tags) in posTagged if tags in ('NNP','NNPS') ]`
```

Here I can extract the Noun entities. But how can I tag them as business-related? For More clarification I am giving an example.
example. Let assume this is a part of article

```
`Microsoft Corporation is an American multinational technology company with headquarters in Redmond, Washington. It develops, manufactures, licenses, supports and sells computer software, consumer electronics, personal computers, and services.Its best known software products are the Microsoft Windows line of operating systems, the Microsoft Office suite, and the Internet Explorer and Edge web browsers.`
```

Now the task is to extract type of product Microsoft develops. Simply the answer would be - `computer software, consumer electronics, personal computers, and services`. The problem is how do I make computer understand this?

Comment: please define "business-related"

Comment: this sounds like you need `sci-kit learn` in addition to `nltk`. `ntlk` could normalize the text, while `sci-kit learn` could train, test and cross-validate a module that predicts from words the "business"

Comment: @Marat I only want to extract word like 'Retail Banking' or 'Courier Service' or 'Steel Plant' which can be tagged as business related words.

Comment: @SOUBHIKRAKSHIT how did you come up with these ones? is it a finite list or do you think it is "intuitive"?

Comment: @Marat I have just mentioned a few example. Their could be many more.

Comment: @SOUBHIKRAKSHIT you need to define which ones of these "many more" are business related. Even if you talk to a different person, your definitions of "business-related" will be slightly different; computers simply wont' figure it out without your help.

Comment: @Maratplease check the updated question.

Comment: NLTK calls this *chunking* but there is no built-in database to identify chunks as "business-related". This is probably not well-defined anyway; business niches is not a closed category, so you cannot predict whether "pork bellies" or "blood diamonds" is "business" without external information about the world. This is arguably too broad for Stack Overflow and I have voted to close this question as such.